# arduino PWM temperature inexpected results

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, temperature-sensor

I am making a system which regulates the temperature of a plate. 
using the PID library
I programed the system as followed:

```
/********************************************************
 * PID Basic Example
 * Reading analog input 0 to control analog PWM output 5
 ********************************************************/

#include <PID_v1.h>
#include "math.h" 

int val, output2; 
//Define Variables we'll be connecting to
double Setpoint, Input, Output;
//Specify the links and initial tuning parameters
PID myPID( &Input, &Output, &Setpoint,0,20,20, DIRECT);

void setup()
{
  //initialize the variables we're linked to
  Setpoint = 37; //temperature a reguler 

  //turn the PID on
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  myPID.SetOutputLimits(-100, 100);
  myPID.SetMode(AUTOMATIC);
  Serial.begin(57600);
  while (!Serial); 
}

void loop()
{
  // phase haute
  //delay(100-output2);
  val = analogRead(1);
  float mv = ( val/1024.0)*5000; 
  Input = mv/10;
  myPID.Compute();
  {   output2 = map(Output, -100, 100, 0, 200); 
      Serial.print("output is :");
      Serial.println(output2); 
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      delay(output2);
      // phase basse
      digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  }
  //analogWrite(5,Output);
  //Serial.print("input temperature is :");
  //Serial.println(Input);
  // Serial.println(Output);
  // Serial.println(Input);

}
```

As you can see in the code the output result is between 0 and 100. 
the temperature desired in the plate is 37 degre. and the actual temperature is 24 degre. consequently, the program supposes to set the value of the output to the max value to reach to 37 degre. 
But the problem is my output is setting to different values as you can see here: [image]

what can be the problem here ? thank you in advance

Comment: Could you add the value of `Input` to the serial print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gerben said in a comment, you should add the value of Input to the serial print, to facilitate problem diagnosis.  As your question stands, one can only speculate about what the problem might be.  My speculation is that the system is unable to cope with parameters (Kp, Ki, Kd) = (0, 20, 20), ie, that it's unstable and unresponsive without proportional control.

Comment: you are right jwpat7. after changing the value of Ki. the output works very well, and the value of it is setting to the max which is 200.

Comment: @zakaria, I meant to call the first parameter Kp instead of Ki (and your 0 value for Kp was why I referred to "without proportional control") and have now corrected that in my answer.  That is, the parameter order in the PID constructor is `(&inputreading, &controloutput, &setpoint, Kp, Ki, Kd, direction)`.  Glad it worked!